# How to get the content of a string after an specific word in caps with R?

Tags: r, regex, string

I am working with a dataset I scraped of the transcripts from the Mexican President (Adnrés Manuel López Obrador) daily speeches, contained in this [webpage](https://lopezobrador.org.mx/transcripciones/).

The structure of each transcript consist in a main message from the President, another parts from some of his Cabinet members and other parts from the journalists making questions. Each part is delimited by a word in caps.

For example:

> PRESIDENTE ANDRÉS MANUEL LÓPEZ OBRADOR: Es que yo hablé, en mi recorrido que hice por el país con todos los gobernadores, a ustedes les consta, porque muchos de los que están aquí me acompañaron.   Entonces, antes de ir al acto, en la plaza pública, yo tenía un encuentro con el gobernador y ahí hablábamos, y un tema era acerca del papel de los delegados.   Nadie puede decir que no les expliqué de qué se trataba, incluso, en algunos casos hasta públicamente hice mención de que el delegado nunca le iba a faltar el respeto a la autoridad local, al gobernador, al presidente municipal.   Es que hay otras cosas que yo entiendo también. Pero yo eso se los dejo de tarea a ustedes, para que ustedes indaguen, investiguen.   Con todo respeto, ustedes son mirones profesionales, son periodistas, pero muy buenos periodistas.   Ahí término con una.     -PREGUNTA: Agencia de Noticias AP.   Los médicos cubanos que estaban en Brasil, trabajando hasta Jair Bolsonaro, ellos podían venir a México; ¿hay una negociación en ese sentido, para traer a los médicos cubanos a México?     -PRESIDENTE ANDRÉS MANUEL LÓPEZ OBRADOR: No. Eso es una volada de nuestros adversarios, que los queremos mucho, mucho, mucho, pero que son muy mentirosos.     PREGUNTA: Señor presidente, Shaila Rosagel, de Sin Embargo, retomando, nada más, para finalizar este tema de Jalisco y de la violencia.   Cuánto tiempo estiman para que empiece a disminuir la violencia, este tipo de ataques armados. FRANCISCO GARDUÑO YÁÑEZ: El día de hoy se inicia una etapa más en estas Islas Marías, la primera fue cuando su fundación con Porfirio Díaz; la segunda fue cuando estuvo el general Múgica, que empieza la prevención; la siguiente fue en los 70, con Luis Echeverría en lo que fueron la Ley de Normas Mínimas; y ahora en la Cuarta Transformación es el cierre y el respeto a los derechos humanos.

I'm interested in extract only the *parts given by the President*.

In other words, those strings delimited by "PRESIDENTE ANDRÉS MANUEL LÓPEZ OBRADOR:" and "PREGUNTA" or "FRANCISCO GARDUÑO".

How can I extract those particular string or, given the case, remove the remaining ones?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and what went wrong with your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After each of the president's talk, there is another person's chunk of text that follows a format of "." + "Name of the person" + ":". Therefore, you can use the following to extract all president talk.

```
text <- c("lalala_testing_purpose PRESIDENTE ANDRÉS MANUEL LÓPEZ OBRADOR: Es que yo hablé, en mi recorrido que hice por el país con todos los gobernadores, a ustedes les consta, porque muchos de los que están aquí me acompañaron. Entonces, antes de ir al acto, en la plaza pública, yo tenía un encuentro con el gobernador y ahí hablábamos, y un tema era acerca del papel de los delegados. Nadie puede decir que no les expliqué de qué se trataba, incluso, en algunos casos hasta públicamente hice mención de que el delegado nunca le iba a faltar el respeto a la autoridad local, al gobernador, al presidente municipal. Es que hay otras cosas que yo entiendo también. Pero yo eso se los dejo de tarea a ustedes, para que ustedes indaguen, investiguen. Con todo respeto, ustedes son mirones profesionales, son periodistas, pero muy buenos periodistas. Ahí término con una. -PREGUNTA: Agencia de Noticias AP. Los médicos cubanos que estaban en Brasil, trabajando hasta Jair Bolsonaro, ellos podían venir a México; ¿hay una negociación en ese sentido, para traer a los médicos cubanos a México? -PRESIDENTE ANDRÉS MANUEL LÓPEZ OBRADOR: No. Eso es una volada de nuestros adversarios, que los queremos mucho, mucho, mucho, pero que son muy mentirosos. PREGUNTA: Señor presidente, Shaila Rosagel, de Sin Embargo, retomando, nada más, para finalizar este tema de Jalisco y de la violencia. Cuánto tiempo estiman para que empiece a disminuir la violencia, este tipo de ataques armados. FRANCISCO GARDUÑO YÁÑEZ: El día de hoy se inicia una etapa más en estas Islas Marías, la primera fue cuando su fundación con Porfirio Díaz; la segunda fue cuando estuvo el general Múgica, que empieza la prevención; la siguiente fue en los 70, con Luis Echeverría en lo que fueron la Ley de Normas Mínimas; y ahora en la Cuarta Transformación es el cierre y el respeto a los derechos humanos.")

library(stringr)


# step 1: get all the conversation chunk between President … : ------------

president_split <- str_split(string = text,pattern = "PRESIDENTE ANDRÉS MANUEL LÓPEZ OBRADOR: ")[[1]][-1] 


# step2: split all the chunks by :  ---------------------------------------

president_split_2 <- president_split %>% str_split(":")


# step3: remove everything after the last . -------------------------------

get_the_string <- function(string) {

substr(string[1], 1, (gregexpr(pattern = "\\.", string[1])[[1]] %>% max()))

}

sapply(president_split_2, get_the_string)
```

Results:

[1] "Es que yo hablé, en mi recorrido que hice por el país con todos los gobernadores, a ustedes les consta, porque muchos de los que están aquí me acompañaron. Entonces, antes de ir al acto, en la plaza pública, yo tenía un encuentro con el gobernador y ahí hablábamos, y un tema era acerca del papel de los delegados. Nadie puede decir que no les expliqué de qué se trataba, incluso, en algunos casos hasta públicamente hice mención de que el delegado nunca le iba a faltar el respeto a la autoridad local, al gobernador, al presidente municipal. Es que hay otras cosas que yo entiendo también. Pero yo eso se los dejo de tarea a ustedes, para que ustedes indaguen, investiguen. Con todo respeto, ustedes son mirones profesionales, son periodistas, pero muy buenos periodistas. Ahí término con una."

[2] "No. Eso es una volada de nuestros adversarios, que los queremos mucho, mucho, mucho, pero que son muy mentirosos."